# position absolute; gets different results on different screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[**In my game**](http://www.mathracer.net/singleexpert.html), if the car is crashed, the bulldozer running interval is supposed to stop after 1700 on jquery. However, my friends told me the bulldozer doesn't stop on same place on every computer. Although the position of each related element is set absolute, and 1700 is processed same in every computer. why is that?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var jump = new Audio("jump.wav");
    var bulldozer = new Audio("bulldozer.wav");
    var warning = new Audio("warning.wav");
    var fireworks = new Audio("fireworks.wav");

    $('.restart').click(function () {
        location.reload();
    });

    $('.homepage').click(function () {
        window.location.href = 'index.html';
    });

    $(".textbox").focus();



    setTimeout(areyouready, 2000);
    function areyouready()
    {

            throwdice();

            function throwdice()
            {
                var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
                var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
                $(".firstnumber").text(random1);
                $(".secondnumber").text(random2);
            }

            var movingbulldozer;
            movingbulldozer = setInterval(function () {
                var bulldozerright = parseInt($(".bulldozer").css("right"))
                if (bulldozerright < 1100) {
                    $(".bulldozer").css("right", "+=2");
                }
                else {
                    $(".bulldozer").css("right", "-=1500");
                }
            }, 5);


            var winpoint;
            winpoint = setInterval(function ()
            {

                var num1 = parseInt($(".firstnumber").html());
                var num2 = parseInt($(".secondnumber").html());
                var total = num1 + num2;
                var entry = parseInt($(".textbox").val());
                var cartop = parseInt($(".car2").css("top"))

                if (entry == total && cartop == 121)
                {
                    $(".car2").css("top", "-=150");
                    function gobacksoil() {
                        $(".car2").css("top", "+=150");
                    }
                    setTimeout(gobacksoil, 1000);
                    jump.play();
                    $(".textbox").val("");
                    throwdice();

                    var oldscore = parseInt($(".expertscoreboard").html());
                    var newscore = oldscore + 15;
                    $(".expertscoreboard").html(newscore);

                    if (newscore == 150)
                    {
                        clearInterval(movingbulldozer);
                        $('.bulldozer').hide();
                        $('.firstnumber').hide();
                        $('.secondnumber').hide();
                        $(".car2").css("top", "+=150");
                        $(".textbox").val("YOU WON THE GAME!");
                        fireworks.play();
                        $('.fireworks').fadeIn(3000);
                        $('.textbox').attr("disabled", true);
                    }

                }

                else if (entry == total && cartop != 121)
                {
                     warning.play();
                     $(".textbox").val("");
                }

            }, 50);


            var gameover;
            gameover = setInterval(function () {
                var bulldozerdistance = parseInt($(".bulldozer").css("right"))
                var cartop = parseInt($(".car2").css("top"))
                if (bulldozerdistance == 350 && cartop == 121)
                {
                    $(".car2").addClass("crashedcar");
                    bulldozer.play();
                    $('.textbox').attr("disabled", true);
                    $('.textbox').val("game over");
                    endinggame = setTimeout(function ()
                    {
                         clearInterval(movingbulldozer);
                    }, 1700);
                }
            }, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Please show us the code that moves the bulldozer

Comment: can you show some more code and more of what you are trying to do, when should the bulldozer stop?  what browser does it not work in (I assume IE?) the bulldozer disappears after running over the car for me, or not running over the car.

Comment: This happens, because you've an interval with 1 msec delay. Practically that interval is executed once per 10 - 15 msec. Intervals are not accurate, they are only guaranteed to take at least the given time, but depending on activity of the browser (and machine) they might be notifically longer. If you want to have an exact position, where the bulldozer stops, you need to watch its position, and cut the interval when the wanted position has been reached.

Comment: if i click restart I can't enter my answer, it is stuck saying game over

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons why the bulldozer stops different positions.

First, you detect only an accurate position (`bulldozerdistance == 350`), it's unlikely this is true at the moment when it's checked. To fix this you need to use `bulldozerdistance <= 350`.

The second is caused by the first. Most of the times the bulldozer stops only, when the interval is stopped. However, practically that interval (1 msec) is executed once per 10 - 15 msec. Intervals are not accurate, they are only guaranteed to take at least the given time, but depending on activity of the browser (and machine) they might be notifically longer.